# Find out what program is creating a folder

Tags: windows-7, malware, malware-removal, user-folders

Some program (malware I suspect) keeps creating a folder on my Windows 7 Pro desktop titled "gg" with nothing inside of it but another empty folder titled "Administrative Tools". How do I track down what program is making this folder?

**EDIT:**

The behavior seems to have stopped since I finished a virus scan, but overnight I left a program called Process Monitor running to see if I could catch the folder being made. But it caught something almost as strange; several programs are trying to access a folder in `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gg\Startup`! What the heck is going on here? I have 'Show Hidden files' as Enabled and there's no folder called `gg` here since I last deleted it.

[screenshot of Process Monitor overnight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiIXa.png)

Comment: Does this behavior exhibit itself if you boot into Safe Mode?  The tools that could identify what process is creating a folder, are useless in a case like this, since by the time you start the tool the folder is already created.

Comment: The behavior is still happening as I write this, so just point me towards a tool that could work.

Comment: Have you confirmed if it happens while in Safe Mode or not?

Comment: "but another empty folder titled `Administrative Tools`" - These folders are created where exactly on the drive?

Comment: I'm doing a virus scan right now, I'll tell you if it happens in Safe Mode as soon as I get a chance. The folders are created in C:\Users\Me\Desktop, so the folder is C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gg\Administrative Tools

Comment: you aren't using GiGa Synch are you? https://gigatribe.wordpress.com/category/giga-gg/

Comment: No. 11morechars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no rational explanation for why this is the case, but I had ClassicShell installed. I noticed it was being accessed in the stack for all of those CreateFile instances, so on a wild guess I uninstalled ClassicShell and the behavior stopped; the Process Monitor's been clean for days.

Thank you everybody for the help.